# MS word 2010, adding different page numbers to first page of each chapter in a single document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, page-numbers

I need to add roman numbers to first 10 pages and rest must be arabic numbers.
Roman numbers must be on the middle,bottom and roman numbers should be on the top right corner.
But when a new chapter starts, those arabic numbers has to be on the middle of the bottom footer.
How can I do this, I tried page brake, did not work!

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long while since I did this, but you need to set your document up with sections, I think. One section for the Roman number pages, and one section for the rest. Then by looking at the dialog box for page numbers, for each section, you should be able to configure a different kind of numbers for each section.

If you find it does:

I, II, III, [...], X, 11, 12, 13

And it's not what you want, you can set the second section up to start at 1.